# Discrepancy between Etherscan.io and Google Big Query information

Tags: etherscan, balances

I noticed that there are large discrepancies between the balances of addresses in Etherscan vs Google Big Query.

Also some addresses that are listed in Etherscan are not existing in the balances table in GBQ. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to know for sure what causes the discrepancies.

In general different nodes may have different information about the blockchain, but this typically last only for a little while for new data. So, assuming that both Etherscan and GBQ have the latest data (why wouldn't they) my best guess is bugs in the systems. An account has certain balance and it shouldn't be possible to misinterpret that, especially for such big services.

Comment: If you take address 0xA16176f987E3F5388ca8696ca2dCC5c778AB6a19 for example.

https://etherscan.io/address/0xa16176f987e3f5388ca8696ca2dcc5c778ab6a19

Etherscan says that the address has 1.645136155684738078 Ether. If I query this address from the balances table from GBQ, it does not even yield any result.

Comment: I accidentally copied the address with the capital letters, that was the reason why I couldn't find it in the table.